# App icon changed to android icon after updating App

Tags: android, android-studio, android-icons

I recently updated my app to a newer version in Android Studio. However, my App Icon was replaced by the android icon (green head with antenna) after the update. I haven't made any changes to the screenshots in my developer account for my icons. Why has my original icon disappeared?

Comment: double check `android:icon` in your `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Comment: Android Manifest shows android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"

Answer (score 3):

Remove the app from the homescreen then re-add it. Sometimes, if the app is removed and/or tied to a launcher without the app installed it will show that. See if the app is still in the app drawer and re-add it to the homescreen.

Comment: Fixed.  Thanks.  But any ideas why the image icon changes to generic android app, yet the link to the app remains active? Doest seem to make sense.  6.0.1